# Dynamics CRM - Unit Testing a plugin with RhinoMocks give weird result

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm

I am writing a unit test for a plugin using Dynamics CRM with RhinoMocks.
After stubbing out the OrganizationService.Retrieve() method, when I invoke the stubbed out method, I am getting null back.

From what I can see (correct me if I'm wrong), is that the stubbed out method signature must the same as the invocation signature.

Here is my code:

**TestSetup**

```
var someGuid = Guid.Empty;
var organisationServiceMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IOrganizationService>();
```

organisationServiceMock.Expect(x => x.Retrieve("someCrmEntity", someGuid, SomeCrmEntityColumnSetQuery.ColumnSet))
                .Return(new Entity
                {
                    LogicalName = "someCrmEntity",
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                });

**SomeCrmEntityColumnSetQuery Code**

```
public static class SomeCrmEntityColumnSetQuery
{
public static ColumnSet ColumnSet => new ColumnSet("column1", "column2");
}
```

**Invocation Code**

```
var someEntity = organisationServiceMock.Retrieve("someCrmEntity", someGuid, SomeCrmEntityColumnSetQuery.ColumnSet);
```

//someEntity is null

**Things I have tried**

1. Removed the ColumnSet and replaced it with null - this works
2. Replaced the static class SomeCrmEntityColumnSetQuery with a default instance (new ColumnSet())
3. I have set the someGuid to Guid.Empty thinking that it was not "joining" on the correct Guid hence the null return value.
4. I have tried to replace .Expect() with .Stub() - no joy

**Edit**
In the expectation, I have tried the .WhenCalled(...) and that is how I found out that if I replace the columnSet argument with a null in the expectation and the invocation, it works. So it's go to do with something in my static class that represents a ColumnSet. The code works as I have it running in my DEV environment.

If anyone can share some light on this, that would be magic!

Charles

Comment: Please add the full test and the full code invoke, I want to know if your guids are the same. I think `ColumnSet` should be public and the assignment should be `=` instead `=>`

Comment: Sxntk: Edited the code

Comment: `OrganisationServiceMock` is a global variable?

Comment: Nope. It's local. I forgot to copy the var.

Comment: You should declare the mock, before set the expectations `IOrganizationService service = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IOrganizationService>();`

Comment: Applied the fix Sxntk

Comment: Did you try [FakeXrmEasy](https://github.com/jordimontana82/fake-xrm-easy) or [XrmUnitTest](https://github.com/daryllabar/XrmUnitTest) ? They'll save you hundreds of hours trying to mock these calls cause they're already implemented...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer after watching a PluralSight video on RhinoMocks.

My problem was that when setting up the stub, the stub does not take **values** but rather the signature of the method that you are stubbing out. For e.g:

var organisationServiceMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock();

//Wrong
organisationServiceMock.Expect(x => x.Retrieve("someCrmEntity", someGuid, SomeCrmEntityColumnSetQuery.ColumnSet)).Return(new Entity());

//The stub does not care about what values are being sent into the method when invoked but rather if the **method signature types** match.

//Correct
organisationServiceMock.Expect(x => x.Retrieve(Arg.Is.Anything, Arg.Is.Anything, Arg.Is.Anything)).Return(new Entity());

//During the invocation, stubbed method now expects the first argument to be a string, then 2nd to be a Guid, 3rd to be a ColumnSet.

I hope this helps anyone who has also been struggling with this. :)

Comment: If you just want to ignore all the input arguments you can use .IgnoreArguments()